# BOM Recursive CTE / input data to complete the query

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I made my recursive cte query to get the bill of materials of a specific part number, but what I need is for something to ask me which part number I need the BOM from.  It Works fine as it is, it's just not functional if I can't inquire easily about different part numbers.

The query is as follows:

```
WITH BOM_CTE(COMPONENT, PARENT,QTY,LVL)

AS (SELECT i.fcomponent, i.fparent, i.fqty, 1 AS LVL

FROM dbo.inboms AS i INNER JOIN dbo.invcur ON i.fparent = dbo.invcur.fcpartno
AND i.fparentrev = dbo.invcur.fcpartrev INNER JOIN dbo.inmastx ON dbo.invcur.fcpartno
=dbo.inmastx.fpartno AND dbo.invcur.fcpartrev = dbo.inmastx.frev

WHERE(i.fparent = '124-5130')

UNION ALL

SELECT     i.fcomponent, i.fparent, i.fqty, BOM_CTE_1.LVL + 1 AS INC_LVL

FROM dbo.inboms AS i INNER JOIN BOM_CTE AS BOM_CTE_1 ON i.fparent=BOM_CTE_1.COMPONENT)



SELECT     B.PARENT, B.COMPONENT, B.QTY, B.LVL
FROM         BOM_CTE AS B LEFT OUTER JOIN
                        BOM_CTE AS C ON B.PARENT = C.COMPONENT
 GROUP BY B.PARENT, B.COMPONENT, B.QTY, B.LVL
 ORDER BY B.LVL
```

As you can see, the WHERE clause in the first part of the CTE will give me the results, but this query as it is can't be represented graphically in Excel, therefore I can't use parameters to ask for the part number.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking - is it 'how do I pass a parameter from Excel into my query'?

Comment: You haven't shown the tables that you're querying or any sample data for their contents, so it's kind of hard to say. Mentioning your database engine and version is generally a good idea too.

Comment: I'm just querying one table named inboms which contains both parent data on one column as fparent and child data as fcomponent.  Running MS SQL 2008 R2.